# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите,нужна ли запятая в предложении:ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬСКИХ СВОЙСТВ ПЧЕЛИНОГО МЁДА ПОСТАВЛЯЕМОГО РАЗНЫМИ ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЯМИ.

Answer (score 5):

Нужна. Причастный оборот стоит после определяемого слова.